# Access mozilla firefox certificate store to HCERTSTORE

Tags: windows, visual-c++, certificate, mozilla, nss

Need to add custom certificate `"MycustomCert.pem"` trusted list in Mozilla Firefox certificate store. How can I modify the trusted Certificate list in Mozilla Certificate store ?

Sample code of getting windows `ROOT` certificate store. Instead of root need to get the access of  Mozilla Certificate to `HCERTSTORE` data structure

```
int main()
{
    HCERTSTORE hRootStore;   

    hRootStore = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, 0, CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG | CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"ROOT");
    if (!hRootStore)
        return 1;  

    CertCloseStore(hRootStore, 0); 
    return 0;
}
```

> give alternative methods are other than using certutils.exe

Comment: Chrome uses the system's certificate store. Firefox and Opera have their own certificate store. Firefox uses NSS, not OpenSSL. I doubt you will be able to use the Windows' APIs to access or modify Mozilla's certificate store (but I don't know for certain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the issue and I have created a batch file for adding certificate to mozilla store,

```
set certificateFile=Ourcert.pem
set certificateName=UurCertName
Set FFProfdir=%Appdata%\mozilla\firefox\profiles
DIR %FFProfDir% /A:D /B > "%Temp%\FFProfile.txt" 
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in (%Temp%\FFProfile.txt) do ( call :Foo %%i  
) 
pause

:Foo
set cetDbLoc=%FFProfdir%\%1
C:\nss3.13.5nspr4.9.1x86\bin\certutil -A -n %certificateName% -t "TCu,Cuw,Tuw" -i %certificateFile% -d %cetDbLoc%
:End
```

You have to download the `nss tools` from `mozilla` and use the `certutil` inside the `nss tools` not the windows default `certutil`

Comment: is there any way to access this within c++?